# Java RMI - send Client stubs to other clients

Tags: java, rmi

I've got to implement something like P2P in RMI. I've created two Remote intrfaces : server and client. Server is responsible for registering clients and returning client stubs to other clients that request it. How should I accomplish this? The method signature on the server looks like this:

```
IClient getClient(String resource) throws RemoteException;
```

The problem is I don't really know how should I implement that regarding the stubs&skeleton issues and that many things is happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about it since JDK 1.5. See the preamble to the Javadoc for UnicastRemoteObject. As long as you quote a port number, even zero, when calling super() or exportObject you don't need stubs. And you haven't needed skeletons since 1998.